# Banach space - Decreasing sequence of closed, non-empty sets - Rational numbers

Tags: functional-analysis

Let the Banach space $E=\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ where $\mathcal{C}([0,1],\mathbb{R})$ denotes the space of continuous functions from $(0,1)$ to $\mathbb{R}$.

Let $\{x_n\}_{n\geq1}, \,(x_i\neq x_j)$ a sequence of rational numbers in $(0,1)$, dense in $[0,1]$ and let ${E_n}$ the subset of $E$ made of functions null at $x_i,\, i=1\dots n$, bounded by $2$ and with integral value 1 on $[0,1]$.

I want to show that ${E_n}$ is a decreasing sequence of closed, bounded and not empty sets.

Comment: You need to show your work and ideas.  You want to show 4 things.  Which of them can you already do, and which of them have you tried but failed?  And for the failures, show what you tried.

Comment: I don't see why the sequence should necessarily be decreasing. Is it because the functions have integral value of 1 while the size of closed balls centred at $x_i$ is decreasing as $x_i$ gets close to zero?

Comment: The sequence $E_n$ is decreasing ... this means $E_1 \supseteq E_2 \supseteq \dots$.

Comment: Ok. So, e.g. $E_2$ must contain functions with zeros at $\{{x_1,x_2}\}$ so is a set of size $\leq$ that of $E_1$, and so on. So indeed, $E_1 \supseteq E_2 \supseteq \dots$. Each set $E_n$ is also bounded because it contains only functions bounded by 2 and is not empty because it contains at least the null function, which is zero for any $x_i$. Is this correct?

Comment: The null function does not have integral $1$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: In order to prove the $E_i$ are not empty, maybe I can prove their intersection $\cap_n E_i$ is not empty.

Comment: Proving $E_i$ nonempty should be much easier than proving the intersection is nonempty.

Comment: What about polynomial functions $f_k$ that have roots in $\{{x_1,\dots ,x_k}\}$,  have integral $1$ on $[0, 1]$ and are bounded by $2$? Surely there should exist one such function in each $E_k$.